# Xcode simulator launch argument for Zoomed display mode?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm looking for a launch argument for the Xcode simulator to launch my app in `Zoomed` mode. Ordinarily, I need to go into the simulator `Settings` > `Developer` > `Display Zoom`

Is there a launch argument that will specify the app launch as `Zoomed` from the start?